# VBA Script Optimization: Compare Data in 2 tables cell by cell

Tags: excel, vba

Please would someone give me some tips on how to optimize the below code? Please see the code below the question.

**Context:**

The problem that I am trying to solve is to compare the data in 2 tables. The primary table is much smaller than the secondary table. The primary table has around 2500 (cells) records and the secondary table has about 75000 (cells) records. The first column in both tables contains the primary key. The goal is to iterate through the first column of the first table and row by row pick out the primary key.

Once we have the primary key - We will need to go to the second table and find the primary key in the first column. I am using the .Find method for this. Once we find the primary key we return the row number associated to that record. At this stage we have now have a mapping between the row number in table 1 and 2 for that key.

Lets say the row number for out first primary key in table 1 is 2. And in table 2 the primary key sits in row 63. I now need to compare the data that lies in column 2 of table 1 against the data that lies in column 2 of table 2 for that primary key. I will need to do this for all columns. What I have then done is say if the two are not equal then make the fill red, else make it green.

The below script is working but it takes around 38 seconds to run. Is there a way to speed this up? I know of the screenupdating, disable events, manual calc etc but from a code perspective is there anything that I can change to improve performance? Also is there something that I might have done wrong that could be improved upon?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated in this regard!

```
'''
Sub Compare2()
Dim a_P As Variant
Dim a_S As Variant

a_P = Query.Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'Primary Table
a_S = Access.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'Secondary Table

Dim x As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim Rng As Range

For b = (LBound(a_P, 2) + 1) To UBound(a_P, 2)
    For x = (LBound(a_P, 1) + 1) To UBound(a_P, 1)
    
        If a_P(x, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            With Access.Columns(1)
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=a_P(x, 1), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                
                    'If not equal - Change to red else change to green
                    If Query.Cells(x, b) <> Access.Cells(Rng.Row, b) Then
                        Query.Cells(x, b).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                       Query.Cells(x, b).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    End If
                    
                End If
            End With
        End If
        
    Next x
Next b

MsgBox "Data check complete.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Data Check Status"

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: One option would be to sort the table by primary key and then compare in incrementing the rownumber of the one with the inferior value.

Comment: You should seriously consider using a SQL database if you are doing this type of operation.

Comment: Reverse the loops so x is outer, b is inner and move the Find outside the inner loop. `Query.Cells(x, b) <> Access.Cells(Rng.Row, b)` Compare array values rather that cell values.

Comment: Hi All - Thank you for the suggestions. Much appreciated - I will try incorporate as needed.

Comment: How many columns need comparing ?

Comment: There are about 15 columns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup repeatedly in a rather large amount of data (your so called secondary table), fastest way is to use a dictionary.

The following code creates a Dictionary. After that it loops over the data of the primary table and compare the value (2nd column) with the value stored in the dictionary.

To speed up the process even more, the code builds two ranges, one for the green cells and one for the red.

To use a Dictionary, you need to set a reference to the Microsoft Runtime Environment (or use late binding)

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim sLookup As New Dictionary
    Dim a_S As Variant, row As Long
    ' Step 1: Build the lookup dictionary
    a_S = Access.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For row = LBound(a_S) To UBound(a_S)
        If Not sLookup.Exists(a_S(row, 1)) Then
            sLookup.Add a_S(row, 1), a_S(row, 2)
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Step 2: Compare Primary table with values of the dictionary
    Dim a_P As Variant
    Dim markGreen As Range, markRed As Range
    a_P = query.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For row = LBound(a_P) To UBound(a_P)
        Dim key
        key = a_P(row, 1)
        If sLookup.Exists(key) Then
            Dim cell As Range
            Set cell = query.Cells(row, 2)
            If a_P(row, 2) = sLookup(key) Then
                If markGreen Is Nothing Then Set markGreen = cell Else Set markGreen = Union(markGreen, cell)
            Else
                If markRed Is Nothing Then Set markRed = cell Else Set markRed = Union(markRed, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Step 3: Set the colors
    If Not markGreen Is Nothing Then markGreen.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If Not markRed Is Nothing Then markRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

This took <1 s on my computer with 2500 / 75000 rows.

Comment: Hi There - Thank you for this. I knew there was a way to get this done more efficiently! I will give this a try.